# Transformer's Primary and Secondary Voltages

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, inductance, phasor, mutual-inductance

In general, which is the phase relationship between the primary and secondary voltages of an ideal transformer? Does it depends on the dot convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is the phase relationship between the primary and secondary
>   voltages

The dot convention tells you which terminals will have secondary and primary voltages in phase: -

[image]

Above picture from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218823/induced-voltages-and-flux-within-a-transformer-and-their-polarities?rq=1). Consider also this picture of two identical windings wound the same way: -

[image]

For any secondary load current, the primary load current will be 180 degrees out of phase at the dotted terminals. Consider this picture for the current: -

[image]

Lower pictures [from here](http://stades.co.uk/index.html#transformers). See also [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128025/transformer-primary-and-secondary-voltage-phase-shift?rq=1) for a wordy version of the above.

Comment: Thank you, I have still another question. So, for analyzing circuits with a transformer with certain given dots, how should we fix the polarities of voltages and currents (with the load convention or source convention? and with respect to the dots?)? Is it an arbitrary choice, since then we will apply the rule "current before crossing the dot and then the inductor for both coils = + M, while if it happens for only a coil =-M"?

Comment: I'd say it's arbitrary; you can talk about primary voltage phase with respect to secondary or vice versa; there is no fixed rule about this. I wouldn't use the term *current before crossing the dot* because clearly that is also the current after the dot.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much